# Passing 2D array by reference C and modify values

Tags: c, pointers, ansi-c

I'm trying to pass a 2x2 char matrix to my function so I can modify it's values inside it. In my code now, the only value that is changed is the first line of the matrix, the line 1 it doesn't change.

in console, my results are

```
     C[0] = ab 
     C[1] =
```

So C[1] is not updating in my function, please, help me to figure out what is going on.

Here's the code

```
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    void changeMatrix(char (*matrix)[2][2]){
        strcpy(*matrix[1], "cd");
        strcpy(*matrix[0], "ab");   
    }

    int main(){
        char C[2][2];
        changeMatrix(&C);
        printf("C[0] = %s \n", C[0]);
        printf("C[1] = %s \n", C[1]);

    }
```

Comment: The strings need space for 3 chars  - 2 letters + '\0' (string terminator).

Comment: that's it. Thank you very much. But now the position 1 comes with some trash.

        C[0] = ab 
        C[1] = t�cd

Comment: There's no need for all that pointer stuff. Remove all the `*` and `&`.

Comment: Yea, now it is working. Thanks

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/tlC8fb)

Comment: 1) C does not support references 2) A pointer is not a reference. 3) The cannonical way is to pass apointer to a 1D array to which a 2D array would decay naturally. 4) Use the index-operator when working with arrays, resp. pointers to the first element of an array.

Comment: If you did pass `matrix` your original way, note that the second row is `(*matrix)[1]`.  Your `*matrix[1]` advances just past the end of the entire 2D array and then dereferences.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you declare a function that receives a matriz in C.
The function prototype should be:

```
void changeMatrix(char matrix[2][2]);
```

Being that the first number in brackets is ignored.
And you should invoke the function like this:

```
char C[2][2];
changeMatrix(C);
```

This is so, because remember that an array's name is the address of the first element in the array. A matrix declared as `char C[n][m]` is an array of n*m positions in which the first m positions belong to the first column, and so forth.

A matrix is then just a kind of one  dimensional array.

Comment: The OP code and your code are both correct ways to pass a matrix by reference. (The OP code makes a mistake inside the function body though)